# blender Python script not running from command line in background mode

Tags: python, command-line

I am using blender from last 2 months and i built a python script to generate animation and it was running pretty nice from command line by `\path\to\blender -b -P script.py` but i dont know it just stopped working for me yesterday after i installed some 3rd party modules, there is not error in script because i have not changed anything in script when it was working fine. what went wrong with blender, i added a line for printing on command line to get to know that does blender call my script, it just did not print anything, it just loads all the modules and stopped after that.

Comment: this might sound boring but you might just be able to make it work by reinstalling blender

Comment: Might be that the 3rd party module isn't working/compatible and blender stops loading addons? Try running with `--debug` to see what goes wrong.

Comment: @gtzkw yeah you are right , i found out the problem, i was importing matplotlib.pyplot which stops blender to execute, i also verified from blender python console, importing matplotlib is fine but can not import pyplot, whats issue? actually i want to see rendered image from command line, is there any other option to do this

Comment: It might depend on a specific version of another module that Blender only offers in a different version (or hasn't even installed).

Comment: but why would it does not give any error like module not found or something, it just exits python console itself as well as my python script  if i try to run it in command line

Comment: Could be because `tkinter` is not installed with blender python.  For using `mathplotlib.pyplot` I run blender using system python (same 3.x version) where tkinter is installed.   btw `pyplot` windows can be opened and controlled from, and without locking,  blender.

Comment: @batFINGER how do we use system installed python for blender, and what did you mean by without locking blender, can you explain a little bit more! and the way i installed matplotlib , do i need to install tkinter also to use pyplot?